# Google Analytics Goal didnt track all orders

Tags: google-chrome, woocommerce, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I created a google analytics goal like this (woocommerce):

[image: I created a google analytics goal like this (woocommerce) :]

but it didn't track all orders . and I see it tracks randomly .

look, I have a order with id 15025 but here i didn't see in goals.

[image: look, I have a order with id 15025 but here i didn't see in goals.]

what should i do ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If the order you are referring to is registered in your CRM but not in Google Analytics it can be considered normal behavior.

There are several reasons why some transactions are not recorded in Google Analytics, for example if:

- the user from the payment gateway does not return to the confirmation page,
- the user uses browser plugins for blocking tracking,
- the user does not have Javascript enabled,
- the user blocks cookies,
- there is an error on the page,
- etc ...

A 5% discrepancy between CRM and Google Analytics can be considered physiological.

If the difference is more than 5% (with a large enough sample size), you have an issue somewhere in your tracking.